# Add a generated jar in the ModuleClassLoader of JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, classloader, urlclassloader, jboss-eap-7

My application generates dynamically some JARS that I need to put in the classpath.

In **Tomcat** I have no problems, due to the ClassLoader extends from URLClassLoader, and I can call *addUrl* method by reflection, and the JAR is available immediately.

```
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(cl, new Object[] { jarUrl });
method.setAccessible(false);
```

But in **JBoss** I'm having problems, because the ClassLoader is a ModuleClassLoader, that it's not an URLClassLoader, so I have not a simple way to add it.

I'm working with JBoss EAP 7.0.0.

Does anybody know if it's possible to do that?

Comment: I finally found another solution based on creating another ClassLoader and set as parent the ClassLoader of JBoss. This is a summary...